# exec() any command in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, execvp

Say in C, I want to call `execvp()` on any string command.  Command can just be:

```
char command[] = "ls -l";
char command[] = "rm *.txt";
char command[] = "cat makefile";
```

I want to put this command variable inside `execvp()`.  So the `exec()` flavored function can just run with any kind of arbitrary command.

How can I do that?  Thanks.

NOTE: `system()` is not allowed.

Comment: Why is `system()` "not allowed"?

Comment: Presumably because he's taking an OS class and they don't allow it?

Comment: Yes, last thing in the assignment I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Clearly, this is homework.  Please tag it as so in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you *have* to call `execvp()`, then you will need to split up those strings into an executable name and an array of arguments (the first being the "name" of the program and the last being a NULL pointer).

That means something like:

```
char cmd1[] = "ls";  char *args1[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
char cmd1[] = "rm";  char *args1[] = {"rm", "*.txt", NULL}; // but see
                                                            // globbing below.
char cmd1[] = "cat"; char *args1[] = {"cat", "makefile", NULL};
```

This is a non-trivial exercise, especially if you want to allow for quoting, globbing, escaping and so forth.

Quoting means you'll have to be careful with commands like:

```
rm "file with spaces.txt"
```

in that you can't simply break on the spaces - you'll have to interpret items in the command much the same as the shell does. Simplistic breaking on spaces would give you a command with three arguments for that string above, rather than the correct one.

By globbing, I mean you'll almost certainly have problems with something like `*.txt` since it's typically the *shell* which expands these arguments. Passing that directly to `execvp()` will result in a *single* argument of literally `*.txt` rather than many arguments matching all the text files in your current directory.

Quoting means that you'll have to handle things like:

```
ls -l "file with spaces and \" quote in it"
```

which will further complicate your parser.

Don't get me wrong, it can be done, but it's probably a damn sight easier just using `system()`.

If you're still thinking of going the `execvp()` route, you'll have to:

- split the string into separate tokens (rather hard, since you have to handle quotes and escapes).
- glob all the arguments, meaning that those with wildcards in them (and only ones that aren't escaped or protected by virtue of being inside quotes) are expanded into multiple arguments.
- construct the argument array, with the command at the front and a NULL at the end.
- call `execvp()` with the parameters being first element in that array and the address of the array.

Comment: Does it mean if I implement an array of null-terminated strings `{"rm", "*foo", "*bar"}`, the `execvp` should execute every combination of matches of `"*foo"` and `"*bar"`? Say, the combinations be `rm *foo[0] .. *foo[n-1] *bar[0] .. *bar[n-1]`.

Comment: Or, instead of `execvp` inside nested loop, it is just a single command that contains expanded (globbed) arguments. Say, `{rm, afoo, bfoo, abar, ..., NULL}`.

Answer (score 5):

No, the `exec` family of functions does not take a single string command line like `system` does. Instead it uses an `argv`-like array of strings:

```
char *command = "/path/to/command";
char *arguments[] = { "command", "first argument", "second argument", NULL };
execvp(command, arguments);
```

Note that the first entry in the `arguments` array is the command itself, and that the array is terminated by `NULL`.

Did you check the manual page?

Comment: yes i have, you said `char *command = "/path/to/command";` can I just do `char *command = "command";` in all the possible cases?

Answer (score 3):

To use any of the execve-style functions, you'll need to parse the command line yourself and build an argv vector. The functions take a char**, where the last element is null - you'll need to allocate enough memory for all this. Then your execve-style call should work.

(p.s. You haven't mentioned anything about fork...)

Comment: Yes, I have fork in my code.  I guess I will have to parse the string.  thanks.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. That's much of what a shell does, really, since there's so much to deal with

Answer (score 1):

In order to have things like "*" ">", "<", "&" etc. to work, you need to execute "/bin/sh" and pass in your command line as arguments. So, it comes down to tokenizing your string.

Comment: While it is convenient to use `/bin/sh`, his homework rules specifically says "no `system(3)`", which is practically the same as _no `/bin/sh`/_.

Comment: sorry about the trouble, I will have to ask if I can use `/bin/sh`.  If I were to use `/bin/sh`, I could do `char *const parmList[] ={"sh", "ls -l", NULL};  execvp("/bin/sh", parmList);` but it seems not right.  syntax error?

Comment: should be `char *const parmList[] ={"sh", "-c", "ls -l", NULL}; execvp("/bin/sh", parmList);`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do here is make the shell parse the command. So consider this:

```
/bin/sh -c 'rm *.txt'
```

That should get you going in the right direction. :)