# How to execvp ls *.txt in C

Tags: c, shell, wildcard, ls, execvp

I'm having issues execvping the *.txt wildcard, and reading this thread - [exec() any command in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089351/exec-any-command-in-c) - indicates that it's difficult because of "globbing" issues. Is there any easy way to get around this?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
char * array[] = {"ls", "*.txt", (char *) NULL };
execvp("ls", array);
```

Comment: For background: Keep in mind that wildcards are expanded by the shell, not by the command. With your code as above, `ls` thinks you're trying to talk about a file that's *literally* called `*.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use the system command:

```
system("ls *.txt");
```

to let the shell do the globbing for you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer this question you have to understand what is going on when you type `ls *.txt` in your terminal (emulator). When `ls *.txt` command is typed, it is being interpreted by the [`shell`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). The `shell` then performs directory listing and matches file names in the directory against `*.txt` pattern. Only after all of the above is done, `shell` prepares all of the file names as arguments and spawns a new process passing those file names as `argv` array to [`execvp`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exec.3.html) call.

In order to assemble something like that yourself, look at the following Q/A:

- [How to list files in a directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program)
- Use [`fnmatch()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) to match file name with a shell-like wildcard pattern.
- Prepare argument list from matched file names and use [`vfork()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/vfork.2.html) and one of the [`exec(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exec.3.html) family of functions to run another program.

Alternatively, you can use [`system()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/system.3.html) function as @manu-fatto has suggested. But that function will do a little bit different thing — it will actually run the `shell` program that will evaluate `ls *.txt` statement which in turn will perform steps similar to one I have described above. It is likely to be less efficient and it may introduce security holes (see manual page for more details, security risk are stated under *NOTES* section with a suggestion not to use the above function in certain cases).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: someone knows what they're doing~!